# How can I connect 4 printers for one USB port

Tags: windows-7, usb, printing, printer, port

can you help me with connect printers. I have one USB data cable from pc USB port and 4 same printers with 4 usb cables.

I connect cable from pc with cable with first printer, everything is ok. But when I connect second printer, driver are installed but in device manager printer is offline and can not priting. I would like to use cable for switch betwen printers where I want printing.

When i send a document on first printer succesfully printed, but when I switch cable to second printer a send a document nothing printed, create printing queue and wait for connect first printer.

printer is a "label 300" http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=24cwt3k&s=9#.WJSIxtLhBrQ

program printer http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2chtmd5&s=9#.WJSI4tLhBrQ

Thank you for help

Comment: How about a USB hub so all 4 are continuously connected?

Comment: No no, 4 cables from printers and one cable from pc. I join only one printer to the cable from computer. If i want print on first printer i link cable from first printer and cable from PC.

Comment: Why go through all that extra effort when a 4 port USB hub will use the 1 port on your PC, and provide 4+ ports for USB devices?  Windows will hate your way!  Sometimes if you wait a long time windows will handle it, but often not going to work.

Comment: Do you want to connect 4 printers to one USB port on laptop or desktop computer? If laptop, what is the model of it?

Answer (score 2):

You could try a USB hub?

Or install a USB card into your PC - you can find many with 4 or 5 ports - and connect each printer individually.

I use this one:
http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/like/161451962746?lpid=107&chn=ps

Another workaround option is for you to set up a network printer connection for each printer - and print to each printer over a network.

Depending onhow you set it up the following could be useful:

http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/New-USB-2-0-Port-Print-Server-Share-LAN-Networking-Network-Ethernet-Hub-printer-/271890367888?hash=item3f4dedc590:g:bhsAAOSwKrhVb8vI

http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/like/161451962746?lpid=107&chn=ps

Comment: I have not tried. When I buy it will work as I describe? I want manage via cable which printer will printing.

Comment: @FiínekCahů You manage which printer prints from the print dialog not by swapping cables ...

Comment: @FiínekCahů  Manage via cable? Why?  Connect all 4, and simply use the power ON/OFF button/switch on the printer.  Then unless it is ON it will not print.  OR you could just change the default printer in windows to switch between them.

Comment: not sure what you mean by manage via cable - if you use any of the above methods, and the USB hub will probably be cheapest and easiest - you choose the printer you want to use, when you are in the print dialog - windows will know which drivers to use and which printer it is. You can name each printer differently to differentiate them if you need to.

Comment: manage - when I connect for example second printer, I dont manage which usb port use. Simple: I want all printers are on the same port and only between them switch cable where I want print.

Comment: then if you use a HUB, you just click print and don't have to plug or unplug any cables - it will save wear and tear also.